# Multiplication table without prompt

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a multiplication table without using prompt.

I think the code is correct, but instead of using the number that I put in it returns `NaN`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="num" placeholder="Insira aqui um numero de 1 a 12..."/>
        <button id="botao">Fazer tabuada</button>

        <script src="js/exercicio2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
var tabuada = document.getElementsByTagName("num");
var button = document.getElementById("botao");
var numero = parseInt(tabuada);

function mult() {
    for(i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        document.write(numero + " x " + i + " = " + numero * i + "</br>");
    }
}

button.addEventListener('click', mult);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

The `Element.getElementsByTagName()` method returns a live `HTMLCollection` of elements with the given tag name. You can't parse that into an int.  If you look into the object you are being returned you can find the answer (I would provide more - but it looks like this is a learning exercise).

Comment: `tabuada` comes from `getElementsByTagName()`.  Your point is still correct.

Comment: yes it is a learning exercise, but how could i get the numbers to do it then?

Comment: We provided plenty of help to solve it on your own, without providing the answer.  But google "parse int from input box" would have provided some solid insight.